# merge/match two data frames based on partially overlapping variables

Tags: r, merge, dataframe

I want to merge/match two data frames based on partially overlapping variables.

Inputs (example):

```
Data.frame_A
X1          X2  X3
aaa,bbb,ccc 25  AGF
ddd,eee,fff 23  BGD


Data.frame_B
Y1  Y2
aaa 25
fff 23
```

Results:

```
Data.frame_C
Z1  Z2  Z3
AGF 25  aaa
BGD 23  fff
```

So far I tried some unix commands and R (e.g. merge), but can't get it to work...

Answer (score 3):

`merge` does work

```
> Data.frame_C <- merge(Data.frame_A, Data.frame_B, by.x="X2", by.y="Y2", sort=FALSE)[, -2]
> Data.frame_C
  X2  X3  Y1
1 25 AGF aaa
2 23 BGD fff
```

Basically, `Data.frame_C` above is what you want, but if you really want the output shown in your question, then two more lines of codes are needed:

```
> Data.frame_C <- Data.frame_C[ , c(2,1,3)]
> colnames(Data.frame_C) <- c("Z1", "Z2", "Z3")
> Data.frame_C
   Z1 Z2  Z3
2 AGF 25 aaa
1 BGD 23 fff
```